# jquery I how do I hide 50% of an element?

Tags: jquery

ok I can't find an answer to this....  and am hoping for help....

I want to hide 50% of an element or hide if element goes beyond X children.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
   </li>
<ul>
```

if there are more than 3 div in this list - hide them.

Comment: Please describe this better and show an attempt at some jQuery code.

Comment: Why are you putting `div` tags within a `li` element? `$('ul li div:gt(2)').hide()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the children programmatically and decide which ones to operation on in your code:

```
function hideChildrenAbove(n) {
    var items = $("#list li").children();
    for (i = n; i < items.length; i++) {
        items.eq(i).hide();
    }
}


hideChildrenAbove(3);​
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/SmVfA/

---

Or you can dynamically build a selector string using `:gt(n)` and letting the selector do the work:

```
function hideChildrenAbove(n) {
    $("#list li div:gt(" + (n - 1) + ")").hide();
}

hideChildrenAbove(3);​
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/pAdqn/

---

Here's an example where clicking on the children causes any children more than 3 to toggle:

```
function toggleChildrenAbove(parent, n) {
    var items = $(parent).children();
    for (i = n; i < items.length; i++) {
        items.eq(i).toggle();
    }
}


$("#list li").click(function() {
    toggleChildrenAbove(this, 3);
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/9nQPL/

Comment: how would I show them if I wanted to do a click function?

Comment: @JustinPiatti - create a click handler and call this function from the click handler.  For a more specific answer, you'd have to show your HTML and describe exactly what you want to click on and what item you want hidden when that is clicked on.  A click handler is extremely basic stuff so perhaps you'd be best starting with a simple jQuery tutorial and working your way through that.  I don't have any specific tutorial to recommend, but a Google search for [jQuery tutorial](http://bit.ly/TBZh1I) shows a lot to choose from.

Comment: @JustinPiatti - I added a click handler example to my answer.

Comment: Sorry - was getting it worked out while you did that.... I didn't mean to imply that I didn't know how to implement the click handler... What I meant was what was the best way to invert the function - but you provided an answer similar to what I sorted out..... Thank You!!! You Rock!

Answer (score 0):

**css:**

```
ul li div{
   display:none;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('ul li div:lt(3)').show();
```

This uses the JQuery selector of 'less than'. There is probably a cleaner way of doing this but if you know for you that you only ever want to display the 1st 3 divs then this should work.

http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/

Answer (score 0):

First you need to count the elements. In this case would be.

```
var elementCount = $("li").children("div").length;
```

And then you hide

```
$("li").children("div").css("display", "none");
```

Would be great if you can put an id in the tags